# Recover corrupted php files in netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans-8

When my laptop got stuck I restarted the pc. Unfortunately, when I open the NetBeans after restart it erased the entire php file. I don't have a backup.

Please help me to recover. I can pay for the work.

Thanks

Comment: Feel free to try phpstorm :P I hope you find a solution.

Comment: Well. Im sorry for your loss, but this question is too broad.

Comment: Someone please help me with this. Is it possible to recover the file?

Comment: I dont think you can... Maybe now you start to do back ups every certain time

Comment: Probably impossible to recover if the file was never saved.   Do you have auto-save enabled?  If so, it may be possible to recover from the filesystem.  Auto-save and version control are two things that can save you from losing important files.

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans has a local history feature - check if you have anything there. With some luck you will be able to restore last saved version of a file.

[image]

But you should learn something from this situation:

1. Always do a backup. You should have a backup of every file which has any value for you - it is only a matter of time when you lose something and backup may save your life then. Don't forget to test that your backup actually works.
2. Use some [version control system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) for your code. With [git](https://git-scm.com/) you can easily create local repository with your project history.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your suggestion. My bad luck there is no local history. When I try to open the php file with notepad++ everything was NULL NULL values. So I think i should redo the code.